# MySQL Interview ,which made me disqualified for the job

Tags: mysql

I was given this MySQL Interview Question, which made me disqualified for the job.

I went to interview and was asked a question which I was not able to reply and I lost the job.

They asked.

We have two tables, the first table (master table) is `CANDIDATES` with fields:

- `candidate_id` (primary_key)
- `candidate_name`

The Second table (child table) is `CANDIDATE_VOTES` with fields:

- `v_id` (primary key)
- `candidate_id` (foreign key)

Every time a vote is given the candidate's candidate_key is put in the child.

`CANDIDATE`:

```
=================================     
|candidate_id | candidate_Name  |  
|-------------------------------|  
| 1           | abc             |  
|-------------------------------|  
| 2           | xyz             |  
|-------------------------------|  
| 3           | etc             |  
|-------------------------------|
```

`CANDIDATE VOTES`

```
==========================     
| votes_id | candidate_id |  
|-------------------------|  
| 1        | 1            |  
|-------------------------|  
| 2        | 1            |  
|-------------------------|  
| 3        | 2            |  
|-------------------------|
```

The Question was *how would you declare a winner*?

Please help me how to do it.

I tried a lot but could not find the logic.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should return all candidates who have the most number of votes:

```
SELECT   candidates.*
FROM     candidates JOIN candidate_votes USING (candidate_id)
GROUP BY candidate_id
HAVING   COUNT(*) = (
  SELECT   COUNT(*)
  FROM     candidate_votes
  GROUP BY candidate_id
  ORDER BY votes DESC
  LIMIT    1
)
```

See it on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/77337/1/0).

Comment: Thanks eggyal..thank you very much..  The answer you provided, done the job..  Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `COUNT()` to get the total number of votes associated with each candidate.  By joining the two tables, you can return the `candidate_name` and if you use a `LIMIT` and `ORDER BY` on the query it will return only the record determined as the winner.

```
SELECT count(*) winner, c.candidate_Name
FROM candidates c
INNER JOIN candidate_votes cv
   ON c.candidate_id = cv.candidate_id
GROUP BY c.candidate_Name
ORDER BY winner desc
LIMIT 1  -- remove the LIMIT to see all records
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/36c64/1)

or MySQL allows to `GROUP BY` on fields not in the `SELECT`

```
SELECT count(*) winner, , c.candidate_Name
FROM candidates c
INNER JOIN candidate_votes cv
   ON c.candidate_id = cv.candidate_id
GROUP BY cv.candidate_id
ORDER BY winner desc
LIMIT 1 -- remove the LIMIT to see all records
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/36c64/2)

Comment: @eggyal I personally would not use a `LIMIT` on the query and return all rows

Comment: But then you're not answering the question of who won...

Comment: @eggyal I disagree returning all rows allows you to see the total votes for all candidates and then you can see who won.

Comment: But surely, especially as an interview question, the machine is being asked to output the winner's name.  Outputting all the contestants and their scores, even if sorted, doesn't really do that... imagine the purpose was to automatically generate a list of trophy winners to be sent to an engravers.  As an interviewer, I'd give this answer due credit, but it wouldn't get full marks.

Comment: @eggyal again, I disagree with you on that...but I am not going to argue with you.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT   CANDIDATE_NAME, count(*)
FROM     CANDIDATES, CANDIDATE_VOTES
WHERE    CANDIDATES.CANDIDATE_ID = CANDIDATE_VOTES.CANDIDATE_ID
GROUP BY CANDIDATE_NAME
ORDER BY count(*) DESC
LIMIT    1
```

SELECT: you select the candidate names + the amount of votes

FROM: use both tables

WHERE: basicly a join to link the tables

GROUP BY: Group the votes per candidate name, the count(*) in the SELECT will show you the amount of lines that were grouped into 1 line (a.k.a. the amount of votes per candidate)

ORDER BY: order by amount of votes highest to lowest

LIMIT: Will only return 1 row, remove this line to see complete list of candidates and votes

Comment: @eggyal, removing the limit ofc, or adding a max in the select

Comment: But then you're not answering the question of who won...

Comment: The basic idea here is that @bluefeet didn't know where to start, the thing he probably needed to know is how to use count(*) and group by

Comment: And yet the interviewer was almost certainly testing for deeper insight than that.

Answer (score -1):

There are several ways to this. One would be to use a GROUP BY:

```
SELECT TOP 1 C.candidate_id, C.candidate_name, COUNT(1) NoOfVotes
FROM CANDIDATES C
INNER JOIN CANDIDATE_VOTES CV ON C.candidate_id = CV.candidate_id
GROUP BY C.candidate_id, , C.candidate_name
ORDER BY 3 DESC
```

This statement creates one row for each vote then groups these rows by candidate and counts how many rows are there for each candidate. Then it orders by the counted votes per candidate and selects the top 1 (doesn't deal with ties though).

Edit: This answer is valid for T-SQL (SQL Server). It seems from the other answers that you need to use "LIMIT 1" at the end instead of the "TOP 1" at the beginning for MySQL.

Comment: I said in my post that it doesn't deal with this situation. You either leave it to human intelligence by removing the limit or you can do a subselect in a having clause to select all candidates wit the most votes (like you did in your post). The question asked to declare a winner, so could argue both ways (or even to return nothing if there is a tie).

Comment: Aye, I just suspect the interviewer was looking for candidates to consider that possibility and yet still answer the question of *who won* rather than list everyone and their votes for human interpretation.

Comment: Right, but the goal here is to educate the OP about SQL, not answer the interview question correctly.

Comment: Fair point, but the two aren't mutually exclusive.  And given that SO answers are intended to remain applicable & useful to wider audiences than the OP, I dare say others would find a correct answer to the question very helpful indeed.

Comment: What is the chance they will find this particular answer when they look for that kind of problem, given that the question is titled "MySQL Interview ,which made me disqualified for the job"? Anyway, it's back to work for me.

Comment: hello n Thanks everybody  who answered  my question n helped me.  Please dont argue with each other.Every solution provided by you all really helps me to learn.What interviewer wanted is another thing than what I was looking for? I happy that from both points of view solutions are perfect. I really thanks you all n thanks to STACKOVERFLOW..